# 'DB2ExecutionContext_ibm_db' object has no attribute 'compiled_parameters'

Tags: sql, database, jupyter-notebook, db2

I ran into a problem while querying on ibm-db2 cloud.

I checked the db connection. The connection is okay but whenever I try to query something (anything) it gives me this error.

**'DB2ExecutionContext_ibm_db' object has no attribute 'compiled_parameters'**

a snapshot of the error -

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-ec7ae9958cc4> in <module>
......
......

~/conda/envs/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ibm_db_sa/ibm_db.py in pre_exec(self)
     47     def pre_exec(self):
     48         # if a single execute, check for outparams
---> 49         if len(self.compiled_parameters) == 1:
     50             for bindparam in self.compiled.binds.values():
     51                 if bindparam.isoutparam:

AttributeError: 'DB2ExecutionContext_ibm_db' object has no attribute 'compiled_parameters'
```

Any solution ?

Comment: Please edit your question to add details of the version of ibm_db, the linux distro and version, the text output of `pip freeze`, whether you are using conda , and the jupyter version, and whether your Db2-on-cloud plan is the lite (free) plan or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could check for these installment if you haven't

!pip install sqlalchemy==1.3.9

!pip install ibm_db_sa

I got the same error and this helps

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I checked back after 1 month and it's all resolved. I completed the course and submitted my final assignment successfully. Something was wrong with IBM Db2